# How do I write all data from Windows Form to a .txt file?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a small membership type form. It consists of 1 X Form with the following inside:

> 4 Group boxes - and inside each is a couple of text boxes, radio buttons and check boxes.

at the bottom of the page I have a register button which should capture all the checked boxes, radio buttons and text that I specify.

```
private void Bregister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextWriter txt = new StreamWriter("member.txt");
    txt.Write("First Name:" + tfirstn.Text "\r\n" + "Last Name:" + tlastn.Text "\r\n" + "Address:" + taddr.Text "\r\n" + "Mobile Number:" + tmobi.Text "\r\n" + "Recucrring Payment Amount:" + trpa.Text "\r\n" + "Account Number:" + taccnbr.Text "\r\n" + "Frequency:" + rweek.Text "\r\n" + DateTime.Today.ToString());
    txt.Close();
}
```

Comment: And where is the problem? What is your question?

Comment: If you were using data binding, you could have a model which the form controls are bound to, and then simply serialize that model to JSON (or similar). Either way, it looks like your current code ought to work. Is it not?

Comment: `File.WriteAllText("member.txt", "First Name:" + tfirstn.Text + "\r\n" + "Last Name...);`

Comment: "_Unclear what you're asking.  
Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question._" Is a close reason and I think this applies here.

Comment: Sorry guys, should have phrased it better i guess.. When I click on the Register button it is not writing all that info into the txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Techncially, you missed several `+`:

```
 ("First Name:" + tfirstn.Text "\r\n" + "Last Name:" + tlastn.Text "\r\n" ....
                              ^                                   ^
                              Here and here should be pluses +
```

I suggest:

1. Organize all lines with a help of `string.Join` (readability)
2. Use same format everywhere (maintainability) - `Date:` added
3. When working with `Date`, let's specify *format* (since it's culture dependent)
4. Let's get rid of streams and use simple `File.WriteAllText`
5. Let's separate UI (`Bregister_Click`) and business logic (saving data)

Code:

```
private void SaveData(string fileName) {
  string data = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
    $"First Name:               {tfirstn.Text}", 
    $"Last Name:                {tlastn.Text}",  
    $"Mobile Number:            {tmobi.Text}",   
    $"Recurring Payment Amount: {trpa.Text}", // Typo? "Recucrring"
    $"Account Number:           {taccnbr.Text}",
    $"Frequency:                {rweek.Text}",
    //DONE: added name - "Date" and Date format
    $"Date:                     {DateTime.Today.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")}" 
  );

  // Or File.AppendAllText if you don't want to rewrite file if it exists
  File.WriteAllText(fileName, data);
}    

private void Bregister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  SaveData("member.txt");
}
```